# How to safely discard golang database/sql pooled connections, for example when they point to a read-only replica?

Tags: postgresql, go, database-replication

We have been using golang's `database/sql` and `github.com/lib/pq` with a PostgreSQL cluster, meaning that a certain database server that was a replication master might be a read-only replica after the previous master has failed.

Recently, our low-usage service managed to keep a single connection in its connection pool (there were no concurrent requests that would have opened a second connection), and its target had been demoted to a read-only replica. As a result, each write operation to the service failed until it was restarted. That would not have happened, if a new connection was made to the cluster.

The problem is I can't find a documented way to discard a connection on certain kinds of errors. The only public method in `database/sql` that sounds correct is `Conn.Close` which returns the connection to the pool without closing it. Not calling it will cause a resource leak which will eventually make the pool unusable. Is there a sustainable way to get rid of a connection when the application wants to?

Comment: You can force a second connection, by starting a transaction on the first, then opening a second connection, before committing or rolling back the transaction. But that's only a possible work-around.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you demote a postgres master without restarting it (which breaks connections)? You can't turn on replication at runtime, right?

Comment: @Peter I'm curious, too, since after asking I realised that a TCP connection made to the previous master must have died in the failover - but I nevertheless got a read-only connection hanging in my pool. My best explanation now is that the connection was acquired between the actual failover and the DNS change reflecting the failover. The DB implementation is Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL, if that is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that when using `database/sql`, the answer is "no", though I'd be happy to be corrected.

A while back, we switched from `database/sql` with `lib/pq` to the pure Go [jackc/pgx](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx) for similar reasons (the inability to control connections on a low level), and were happy with the result. That module offers [`ConnPool.Reset`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#ConnPool.Reset) which sounds like what you want here:

> Reset closes all open connections, but leaves the pool open. It is intended for use when an error is detected that would disrupt all connections (such as a network interruption or a server state change).
>
> It is safe to reset a pool while connections are checked out. Those connections will be closed when they are returned to the pool.

Comment: It will be quite unfortunate if the only answer is not to use the standard library, but +1 for a possible alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably Postgres's [DISCONNECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-sql-disconnect.html) command.

```
_, err := conn.ExecContext(context.Background(), "DISCONNECT")
```

will cause the connection to be closed, from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can discard it by using the Raw function and returning a driver.ErrBadConn error:

```
conn.Raw(func(interface{}) error { return driver.ErrBadConn })
```